# DaskLGBMClassifier.fit() error: 'Future' object has no attribute 'get_params'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, dask, lightgbm

I'm trying LGBM's Dask API and when I fit DaskLGBMClassifier I get the following error: 
'Future' object has no attribute 'get_params'
I tried to deug it working on the original code. The variable model that you can see in the error reference that Colab should be an instance of the class `LGBMModel`, which seems to **have** the method `get_params()`.  
Why does it say that `get_params` is an attribute? What is a 'Future' object?

this is the image of the error [image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTJPi.png) , this the [`model=_train`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C67qX.png), this the [_train](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFqzU.png) function, this the [`LGBMModel`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHgdo.png) adn finally the [get param function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJtvw.png).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please don't share images of code and logs, and instead share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with code (and error messages as text) that others could use to reproduce the error you're facing.